# CV2: Import Error in Python OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, anaconda

I have Anaconda installed in my system and I recently installed OpenCV 3.0.0 using the instructions given on [this](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/introduction/linux_install/linux_install.html) page. But when I open python and type import cv2, it throws me the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: /home/ashutosh/anaconda2/lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found (required by /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cv2.so)
```

I dont't know why am I getting this error. I also put the PYTHONPATH in the bashrc file, sourced it but nothing happened.

Comment: `sudo apt-get install libgcc`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sudo apt-get install libgcc`

This dependency caused the error.

Comment: Please accept this answer, so this question does not remain unanswered.